# save todays date to file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

Trying to include date into a filename when the file is written.

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath + todaysDate.ToShortDateString() + ".dat");
```

Error:

```
 Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sales\Import11/02/2014.dat'.
```

Possible to change date to separated by _ ? or any other suggestions to resolve this?
Ta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to format the date in a way which you know it won't conflict with the file path, an underscore `_` or a `-` or no separator at all are better alternatives

```
string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, 
    String.Format("{0}.dat", todaysDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

Comment: In general, yyyy-MM-dd is better than dd-MM-yyyy, as it's naturally sortable.

Comment: You should use yyyy-MM-dd as you will be able to sort files in correct order.

Comment: Also you almost certainly want to use the invariant culture, unless you really want it to switch to a different calendar system in some countries...

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the date so it doesn't have illegal or unwanted characters.

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath + todaysDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd_HHmmss") + ".dat");
```

[Here is a list of all of the format options for Date and Time.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using another delimiter, such as underscore `_`

`todaysDate.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss");`

`/` is not a valid character for a file path. You can use various other characters, as long as they are not illegal for a file path.

This MSDN reference should help.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
string destFile = string.Format("{0}{1:yyyy_MM_dd}.dat" , targetPath, todaysDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
var title = String.Format("NameOfYOuWant {0}.log", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '-'))
```

Comment: This is non-safe way to do this as it will still depend on current culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- Using a sortable date format, just because that's naturally pleasant
- Explicitly specifying the invariant culture, to avoid oddities of ending up using a different calendar system. (I *suspect* you always want to use the Gregorian calendar.)
- Explicitly specifying delimiters which aren't going to cause problems in a file system path (which `/` and `:` do)

So something like:

```
string name = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "Import-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.dat",
                            DateTime.Today);

// Assuming that targetPath is the directory; it's slightly unclear.
string path = Path.Combine(targetPath, name);
```

Note:

- By using `Today`, you're using the system local time zone. That may well be what you want, but you need to consider it explicitly.
- You're only using the date, rather than the date and time - is that definitely okay? Will you ever need to handle multiple imports on the same day?